# Apache htaccess RewriteRule

Tags: .htaccess

I am not sure this can be done in `.htaccess` file what I am trying to do is when I type the web address Example: `https://www.examplesite.com` I want `.htaccess` to open `https://www.examplsite.com/signin`
is this possible in `.htaccess` file?

I have tried several examples that open specific index pages like `index.htm` `index.html` `index.php` but here I want the root to open `https://www.examplesite.com/signin` is it even possible ?

Comment: Try this `DirectoryIndex /signin`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible and readily supported via the "RedirectMatch" directive. This uses a simple regex expression to test for "root" condition and then accordingly redirect.

In your case, you'll need to add this line at the top (earlier than any other redirect rules) in the htaccess file...

```
RedirectMatch ^/$ "/signin/"
```

If this redirection is a permanent requirement, just modify the line above to

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/$ "/signin/"
```

Better to specify the response status code to avoid SEO ambiguity.

Comment: I tried both and the first one opens the page but when I try to log in it is a broken page sure it has to do with code on my end and does show it achieved what I needed now I just need to check some things on my side so thank Prasad Paradkar

Comment: Glad to hear it! If this has helped you please do accept it as the answer.